# Continuity theorem for Laplace transform: limiting function uniqueness

Tags: probability-theory, laplace-transform

Let $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $[0,\infty)$. Assume we know that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int e^{-tx}\mu_n(dx) = \psi(t)$ for $t\geq0$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\psi:[0,\infty)\to[0,1]$ is a map continuos in $0$.

How can I show that $\psi$ is the Laplance transform of a probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$? (This is Ex 15.3.4 of Probability Theory by A. Klenke, 3rd version).

My main doubt is that, if I am able to show that the sequence of $\mu_n$ is tight, how can I check that the limit function $\psi$ is a Laplace transform and not something else? (Basically I am trying to apply Theorem 13.34 of the same book for the interested ones).

**Edit**

How would you check the tightness of the sequence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tightness there is a subsequence $(\mu_{n_k})$ converging weakly to some probability measure $\mu$. Since $e^{-tx}$ is a bounded continuous function we get $\psi (t)=\int e^{-tx}d\mu(x)$ for all $t \geq 0$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $\psi (0)=1$ and $\psi$ is continuous at $0$ we can find $r$ such that $\int e^{-rx}d\mu_n(x) >1-\epsilon$  for all $n$. Now, $$1-\epsilon \leq \mu_n ([0,M])+\int_M^{\infty} e^{-rx}d\mu_n(x) \leq \mu_n ([0,M])+ e^{-rM}\mu_n(M,\infty).$$ This can be written as $\mu_n(M,\infty) \leq   \epsilon +e^{-rM}\mu_n(x)(M,\infty)$. I will let you finish the proof from here.

Comment: Is this result related to the Prohorov's Theorem? My doubts is now that we have only a subsequence that is converging weakly. How can I be sure that the whole sequence converges? Thanks.

Comment: If a sequence of real numbers converges then every subsequence also converges to the same limit.  So $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int e^{-tx}\mu_{n_k}(dx) = \psi(t)$ for $t\geq0$. @Enrico

Comment: Right! Just to see if I am along the correct path: how would you check the tightness property of the sequence?

Comment: @Enrico I have edited.

Comment: I was on the wrong path. Thanks for your time, very clear answer.

Comment: Concluding, according to the tightness definition: I can fix $\epsilon$, which determines  a fixed $r$. Then I can choose $M$ to satisfy the last inequality. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.